# Regular expression for Alphabet, numeric and special character

Tags: .net, regex, special-characters

Can someone please give regular expression for a word, which should have:

1. length in the range of 6 to 10
2. It must be a combination of alphanumeric, numeric and special character (non-alphanumeric character)

Comment: What is the definition of "special character"? Isn't numeric included in alphanumeric?

Comment: Why are we being asked to write your RegEx for you? Have you tried anything that hasn't worked? There are automated tools to generate RegEx for you... Such as RegEx Magic.

Comment: any non-alphanumeric character i.e. all but a-z, A-Z, 0-9

Comment: Alphanumeric includes numeric...

Comment: Well if the regular expression should match if the string consists only of allowed characters then regular expressions are certainly the way to go. But if you want to check if any of the classes "alphanumeric", "numeric" and "special characters" appear at least once in the string then it is easier to write the validation manually than to write a regex which can do that.

Comment: I think what he means, is it must have at least one alpha character, at least one numeric and at least one that's not either of those.And also be between 6 and 10 characters. i.e. it's an attempt at a password complexity check.

Comment: @Ray Exactly..that's what I need. I have never worked on regex. And need to deliver it quickly. That's i posted it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So in other words, all characters are allowed, but at least one letter, one digit, and one "something else" character is required?

```
^(?=.*\p{L})(?=.*\p{N})(?=.*[^\p{L}\p{N}]).{6,10}$
```

I wouldn't impose a *maximum* length restriction on a password, though...

**Explanation:**

```
^                    # Match start of string
(?=.*\p{L})          # Assert that string contains at least one letter
(?=.*\p{N})          # Assert that string contains at least one digit
(?=.*[^\p{L}\p{N}])  # Assert that string contains at least one other character
.{6,10}              # Match a string of length 6-10
$                    # Match end of string
```

Comment: Urgh. I think that in cases like these, readability should come before compactness.

Comment: Do you know if the `{m,n}` quantifiers work correctly with Unicode?

Comment: @KAK You can easily solve that using `IgnorePatternWhitespace` (or the `x` modifier)

Comment: ...and as far as length restrictions, I think 255 is long enough for the foreseeable future... :D

Answer (score 0):

You should do this as a sequential series of tests:

1. Is it of the right length? `^.{6,10}$`
2. Does it contain an alphabetic character? `[A-Za-z]`
3. Does it contain a digit? `[0-9]`
4. Does it contain a "special character" `[^0-9A-Za-z]`

If it passes all four tests, it's ok.